# Double Aligning equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

How do I align the $J\mapsto X$ under $\mathcal{J}\to \mathcal{A}$.

My current attempt is,

```
\begin{align*}
    \Delta^\Acal: \Acal &\to \Acal^{\Jcal}\\
    X&\mapsto \Delta^\Acal(X):\Jcal&\to \Acal,\\
 J&&\mapsto X.
\end{align*}
```

This gives a weird result,

[image]

Here `\Acal` stands for `\mathcal{A}`. I don't want to do it in tikzcd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a nested `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Acal}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\Jcal}{\mathcal{J}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
  \Delta^{\Acal}\colon \Acal &\to \Acal^{\Jcal}\\
                            X&\mapsto 
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    \Delta^{\Acal(X)}\colon \Jcal &\to \Acal,\\
                                J &\mapsto X.
    \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use `^{\Acal}`, it's much safer.